# Display full width background for selected items in jqTree

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqtree

OK, I have a simple nested list, styled with [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree).

[image: Nested list with jqTree styling]

Playing with the inspector, I noticed the appended class, responsible for highlighting elements is `jqtree-selected`.

And the whole thing works quite ok. **Except for one thing:**

I want **the selection background (with the blueish colour) to occupy the full width** of the line, no matter which element is selected. (Currently, the `node1` and `node2` elements, behave fine, but their "children" elements, when highlighted, do not occupy the whole row)

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

---

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/80589tbx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well let's pseudo it... :)

```
.jqtree-selected> .jqtree-element::before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-100%;
    height:21px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(190, 224, 245)), to(rgb(137, 175, 202)));
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80589tbx/2/)

*Thanks to the plugin, it already apply `position:relative` on `.jqtree-element` by default so we don't have to do it.*

Comment: OK, you're my hero! You can't imagine how many hours I've spent on that stupid detail! Btw, your example works fine, however I had to set `top:-1px; height:24px;`. Ah, and for some reason, jsFiddle messed up the colours. In any case, **thanks a lot**! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `margin-left` from following css.

You can find it **jquery.jqtree.css line 12**

```
ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {
display: block;
margin-left: 12px;/**Remove this**/
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: ..and adding `padding-left` I suppose?

Comment: Well, that was the #1 thing I tried. And it's messing the whole thing up. @Mr_Green Adding `padding-left` was the next most sensible thing. Although it's still not working.